# Knockout js how to Implement Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm new on Knockout js.Trying to implement countdown timer on html with using knockout js

For this purpose I added 4 html elements(input, span and start, stop buttons) on view. When start button is pressed, the value that written on `<input>` objects should be passed to `refreshViewModel`, and there will be countdown process. When the countdown is processing remaining time will be showed inside `<span>` element. If the stop button is pressed countdown will be stopped.

If the countdown finishes another function(that is callbacked from another viewModel) which is filtering the page with some parameters will be initiated.

Binded textbox value to span value. I cannot figure out how to count and show to remaining  value inside span dynamically?

Html:

```
<div id="pnlTimer" class="row">
  <div class="span2 pull-right" style="border:1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218)" >
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Reload Interval</span>
    <br />
    <input  id="initialTime" style="width:20px;height:14px" data-bind="value:  initialTime" />
    <span id="remainingTime" style="visibility:hidden"> / 15</span> second(s)
    <button class="btn" style="margin-top:5px" id="StartCounter" data-bind="click: StartCounter">
       <i class="icon-play"></i>
    </button>
    <button style="visibility:hidden;margin-top:5px;margin-left:-44px" class="btn"  id="StopCounter" data-bind="click: StopCounter">
       <i class="icon-stop"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
     @Url.Content("~/Content/App/viewModels/listCasesViewModel.js
     @Url.Content("~/Content/App/viewModels/RefreshPageTimerViewModel.js                       



$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new ListCasesViewModel();
    viewModel.init();

    var pnl = $("#pnlFilterPanel").get()[0];
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, pnl);


    var viewModelTimer = new RefreshPageTimerViewModel();
    viewModelTimer.init();

    var pnlTimer = $("#pnlTimer").get()[0];
     ko.applyBindings(viewModelTimer, pnlTimer);

    viewModelTimer.callBackMethod = viewModel.filter;


});
```

**First viewModel :RefreshPageTimerViewModel:**

```
var RefreshPageTimerViewModel = function () {
var self = this;


self.StartCounter = ko.observable();
self.StopCounter = ko.observable();
self.initialTime = ko.observable();
self.remainingTime = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.initialTime();
}, self);

countDown: ko.observable()


this.init = function () {
    self.Count();

}

this.callBackMethod = function () {
    alert("not implemented!");
}

this.Count = function () {

    var initial = self.initialTime; // initialTime value;
    var remaining = self.remainingTime; 


    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
        this.ExecuteCallBackMethod();
    }
}

this.ExecuteCallBackMethod = function () {
    this.callBackMethod();
}



};
```

**Second viewModel: ListCasesViewModel:**

```
   var ListCasesViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

self.selectedStartDate = ko.observable(null);
self.selectedEndDate = ko.observable(new Date());
self.selectedSearchKey = ko.observable("");
self.selectedStatuses = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedHospitals = ko.observableArray();

// methods...
this.init = function () {
    self.selectedEndDate(new Date());
    self.filter();
}

this.filter = function () {

    // get filter control values
    var startDate = self.selectedStartDate(); // dtStart.value();
    var endDate = self.selectedEndDate(); //dtEnd.value();
    var searchText = self.selectedSearchKey();

    //And Some calculations....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is your ViewModel code, it uses an `observable` where you wanted a function (to Start and Stop the counter). Also, it does not seem to have a clear definition of what it is trying to do.

Also, im assuming you wanted the Start button to show when the timer is stopped, and the Stop button to show when the timer is started - so ive taken the liberty to add this functionality too.

Here is the rewritten view model:

```
var RefreshPageTimerViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.timerId = 0;
    self.elapsedTime = ko.observable(0);
    self.initialTime = ko.observable(0);
    self.remainingTime = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.initialTime() - self.elapsedTime();
    });
    self.isRunning = ko.observable(false);

    self.StartCounter = function(){
        self.elapsedTime(0);
        self.isRunning(true);
        self.timerId = window.setInterval(function(){
            self.elapsedTime(self.elapsedTime()+1);
            if(self.remainingTime() == 0){
                clearInterval(self.timerId);
                self.isRunning(false);
                self.Callback();
            }
        },1000)
    }
    self.StopCounter = function(){
        clearInterval(self.timerId);
        self.isRunning(false);
    }
    self.Callback = function(){}
}
```

A few things to note:

- Has a property `timerId`, which does not need to be observable, but allows us to stop the timer which is used to increment the `elapsedTime`
- has an observable property `isRunning` used to control the visibility of the Start and Stop buttons
- has an empty function `Callback` which can be used to execute any function when the countdown reaches zero.

Here is the new markup:

```
<div id="pnlTimer" class="row">
  <div class="span2 pull-right" style="border:1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218)" >
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Reload Interval</span>
    <br />
    <input  id="initialTime" style="width:20px;height:14px" data-bind="value:  initialTime" />
    <span id="remainingTime" data-bind="text: remainingTime"></span> second(s)
    <button class="btn" style="margin-top:5px" id="StartCounter" data-bind="click: StartCounter, visible: !isRunning()">
       start
    </button>
    <button style="margin-top:5px" class="btn"  id="StopCounter" data-bind="click: StopCounter, visible:isRunning()">
       Stop 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the addition of `visible: !isRunning()` to the start and `visible:isRunning()` to the stop buttons.

Finally, here is the init code:

```
$(function(){
     var viewModelTimer = new RefreshPageTimerViewModel();
    viewModelTimer.Callback = function(){
        alert("finished");
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelTimer);
})
```

Note the creation of a callback function which simply alerts. Your code could be as it was, ie `viewModelTimer.callBackMethod = viewModel.filter;`

Finally, a live example to allow you to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/eF5Ec/

Comment: Thanks,it is the exact example that i am looking for.
Small addition:  "viewModelTimer.callBackMethod = viewModel.filter" reference "filter()" function from 2nd viewModel to 1st one.