# How to lock when timer reaches 00:00

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I currently have a set of cards that can be selected and saved. I also have a timer. What I would like is that when the timer hits 00:00, cards are no longer be able to be selected or saved.
Here is what I have so far, and I attached a fiddle at the end. Thank you in advance!

HTML

```
<div style="clear:both; height: 150px;">
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <div class="profile" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.clicked, enable: active, css: {highlight: active()}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="timer">2:00</div>
<h2>Selected Card</h2>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: save" value="Save"></input>
```

CSS

```
.profile {
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
color: black;
background-image: url(http://images1.pixlis.com/background-image-checkers-chequered- checkered-squares-seamless-tileable-very-light-grey-saltpan-236nwb.png );
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
line-height:80px;
text-align: center;    
margin: 2px;
}
.highlight {
background: yellow !important;
border:1px solid #000;
color: black;
}
```

Javascript/Knockout

```
function Step(number) {
this.active = ko.observable(false);
this.name = ko.observable( number);
}

var model = function () {
var steps = [1,2,3,5,8,13,20,40,100];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < steps.length ; i++ )
steps[i] = new Step( steps[i] );
var items = ko.observableArray( steps )
var selectedItems = ko.computed(function () {
    return _.filter(items(), function (item) {
        return item.active();
    });
})

var clicked = function (item) {
    items().forEach(function(item){ item.active(false) });           
    item.active(!this.active());
};

var save = function () {
    alert("sending items \n" + ko.toJSON(selectedItems()));
}

return {
    items: items,
    selectedItems: selectedItems,
    save: save,
    clicked: clicked
}
}

function countdown(minutes) {
var seconds = 60;
var mins = minutes
function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    var current_minutes = mins-1
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = 
 current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {

        if(mins > 1){  
           setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);

        }
    }
    }
    tick();
    }

countdown(2);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/63yeD/)

Comment: Take a look on [observable Countdown Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467548/knockout-js-how-to-implement-countdown-timer). Just add appropriate `css` binding on `Callback`

Comment: when i added the obserable countdown timer it doesnt seem to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is several possibilities how to achieve this, you can create method via interface which you will call when time is reached. Inside your model you also create observable which will be set to lock state.

```
 var lock = function() {
        disableUIChanges(true);
    }

    var disableUIChanges = ko.observable(false);
```

see example on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gn4A4/4/

I would suggest you also to follow recommendations from http://knockoutjs.com/ documentation. You could create base class like this

```
var MyGame = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.steps = [1,2,3,5,8,13,20,40,100];
   ...
}
```

then create instance of myGame class and applyBindings from game

```
var game = new MyGame();
ko.applyBindings(game);
```